# Jquery replace string element by delimiter

Tags: jquery

I've a string like this

```
var str = "<div class=\"@@obj.classname@@\" style="\@@obj.color@@\">@@obj.content@@</div>";
```

I'd like to create a function to dynamically change it and get this result

```
var result = "<div class=\"" + opt.obj.classname + "\" style="\" opt.obj.color + "\">" + opt.obj.content + "</div>";
```

Is it possibile to do it? How could I do that? the replace function might help? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because this requires the result not as a string but as executed javascript (requiring eval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to execute some code in a string. Before that, you need to make sure your string is proper code, so you would need to replace the @@parameter@@ with the parameter wrapped with `'` and `+`. Something like this:

```
var str = "'" + str.replace(/@@(.*?)@@/g, "' + opt.$1 + '") + "'";
var result = eval(str);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hj3grh1o/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
eval "var result = " + str.replace(/@@(.*?)@@/g, '" + opt.$1 + "');
```